# AddHttpClient<TClient> with just an interface class?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, httpclientfactory

I want to add a httpclient that used to be done like this:

```
AddHttpClient<IClassName, ClassName>()
```

But now, the implementation class is set to an internal class.

```
AddHttpClient<IClassName>
```

The above seems to compile no problem but what is it essentially doing?

How will it know the implementation?

Comment: _"How will it know the implementation?"_ - it doesn't. And just because it compiles doesn't mean it will do what you expect at runtime.

Comment: @Dai Ahh, is there any workaround to linking it with the internal concrete class?

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to accomplish? (In my experience I find _typed HTTP clients_ too much trouble anyway)

Comment: The code is serializing the class so it can be sent in a body of a Request/Response.

Comment: @jdweng I don't see any code that does that.

Comment: @jdweng That is absolute nonsense

Comment: Part of the problem is that C# doesn't have any way to let you add a type constraint like "where T : not-interface" and `where T : class` includes interfaces. So the code compiles but will fail at runtime.

Comment: @DavidG : It is binding a class to a request and the only way it can be accomplished is through a serialization.  Microsoft documentation is poor and the obvious becomes vague.

Comment: @jdweng No, that's not what's happening. It's part of the dependency injection registration for HttpClientFactory. It allows you to configure an `HttpClient` that will be injected into the service named in the generic when that service has `HttpClient` in its constructor. You can do stuff like configuring the base instance, adding delegating handlers to the pipeline, adding retries and circuit breakers via Polly, etc. When using the factory without it, the service would need to accept `IHttpClientFactory` itself and then generate a client or handler using that service.

Comment: @jdweng there's some examples of it in action here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests#how-to-use-typed-clients-with-ihttpclientfactory

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar : How can you send a class without serializing.?

Comment: @jdweng There is no "sending" of classes here, 100% there is no serialisation either. I'm staggered that you don't know what dependency injection is or how it works.

Comment: @DavidG : Microsoft is horrible at explaining low lever interfaces.  There are two common situations that are very similar.  One if the dbContect and second is sending class data over http.  Both cases there is a serialization that is performed to take a class object and send to a different application.  How else can you send class data?

Comment: @jdweng Why would DbContext be sending class data over HTTP? That is so incredibly wrong. Where would it be sending class data?

Comment: @jdweng There is no serialization happening here, there are no web requests happening here, this is simply configuring `HttpClient` for injection into `ClassName`, and then `ClassName` (which might be something like `ProductService` and have methods like `GetProductsAsync`, `CreateProductAsync`, etc. which then use that `HttpClient` in the code of those methods, and would have appropriate serialization code with it). I'm telling you this not because I've misunderstood some documentation, but because I work with this specific code often in my job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```cs
AddHttpClient<IClassName>();
```

This compiles, however, at runtime it will throw an exception saying that it cannot resolve service for type `IClassName`.

In order to be able to keep your `ClassName` internal, and at the same time be able to correctly configure your class, you should have a public Extension method in the project where you have access to `ClassName`:

```cs
public static class ConfigExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddIClassName(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHttpClient<IClassName, ClassName>();
        return services;
    }
}
```

Now you can call:

```cs
services.AddIClassName();
```

in your `Program.cs`/`Startup.cs`

Comment: @Minahil how would you design the extension method if the user wants to use proxy with the HTTP client?